# State supported on meet iff supported on both projections

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra with projections $p,q\in\mathcal{A}$ and a state $\varphi:\mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{C}$. Consider $p\wedge q$ in the bidual $\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}$. Where $\omega_\varphi$ is the extension of $\varphi$ to a normal state on $\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}$, I believe the following to be (almost obviously(!)) true:

> **Proposition:** $\omega_\varphi(p\wedge q)=1$ if and only if $\varphi(p)=\varphi(q)=1$.

The issues I potentially have with the proof are around some technical issues. I will try and flag these with (!!) and hopefully there are no others. I would also be happy to see other proofs.

*Proof:* Assume that $\omega_\varphi(p\wedge q)=1$. Let $\widetilde{\pi_\varphi}$ be the GNS representation of $\omega_\varphi:\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}\to\mathbb{C}$ with cyclic vector $\widetilde{x}\in\widetilde{\mathsf{H}_\varphi}$. As $\widetilde{\pi_\varphi}$ is strongly continuous (!!1), and $\operatorname{sot-lim}_{n\to \infty}((pq)^n)=p\wedge q$:
$$\widetilde{\pi_{\varphi}}(p\wedge q)=\widetilde{\pi_{\varphi}}(p)\wedge\widetilde{\pi_{\varphi}}(q)\qquad(\text{!!2}).$$
Now,
$$\omega_{\varphi}(p\wedge q)=1 \implies\langle \widetilde{x},\widetilde{\pi_{\varphi}}(p\wedge q)\widetilde{x}\rangle=1\implies \widetilde{x}\in \operatorname{ran}(\widetilde{\pi_\varphi}(p\wedge q))$$ and because of (!!2), this implies $$\widetilde{x}\in \operatorname{ran}(\widetilde{\pi_\varphi}(p))\cap \operatorname{ran}(\widetilde{\pi_\varphi}(p)).$$
This implies that, where $p,q\in\mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}$ via the embedding $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{A}^{\ast\ast}$, $\omega_\varphi(p)=\omega_\varphi(q)=1$ which implies that $\varphi(p)=\varphi(q)=1$.

Now suppose $\varphi(p)=\varphi(q)=1$ and let $\pi_\varphi$ be the GNS representation of $\varphi$  with cyclic vector $x\in\mathsf{H}_{\varphi}$ so that
$$\varphi(f)=\langle x,\pi_\varphi(f)x\rangle.$$
That $\varphi(p)=\varphi(q)=1$ implies that $x\in \operatorname{ran} \pi_{\varphi}(p)\cap \operatorname{ran}\pi_{\varphi}(q)$. Now:
$$\omega_\varphi(p\wedge q)\underset{\text{!!3}}{=}\lim_{n\to \infty}\varphi((pq)^n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle x,\pi_\varphi((pq)^n)x\rangle=\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle x,(\pi_\varphi(p)\pi_\varphi(q))^nx\rangle=1,$$
as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your issues are solved from the fact that $\omega_\varphi$ is normal state on a von Neumann algebra, and hence its GNS representation is normal, which is to say that $\tilde\pi_\varphi$ is strongly continuous on bounded sets; which is exactly what you need.

That said, this is a really weird way of doing the proof. You have that $p\wedge q\leq p$ and you are dealing with states, so
$$
1=\omega_\varphi(p\wedge q)\leq \omega_\varphi(p)=\varphi(p)\leq 1,
$$
giving you  $\varphi(p)=1$.

Comment: Yes, I thought it obviously true, and so I thought there must be a much easier way (as you have shown, thank you). It is just I ended up writing down a proof without thinking clearly.